# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table has no column named (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO

Tags: android

I am getting this weird error on some tablets. I use my personal phone to develop the app and I am not getting this from my phone. The tablet giving this error has an Android 11.

What would be the problem?

The real error message is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table registro has no column named es_extra (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO registro(longitud,codigo_template,id_evento,imei_telefono,sincronizado,cedula_supervisor,fecha_registro,latitud,id_asignacion_proyecto,es_extra) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1699)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1596)
```

In the `onCreate` I have this code:

```
db.execSQL(CREATE TABLE registro (id_registro INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fecha_registro TEXT, latitud TEXT, longitud TEXT, id_evento INTEGER,id_asignacion_proyecto INTEGER,codigo_template TEXT,sincronizado INTEGER,imei_telefono TEXT,cedula_supervisor TEXT, es_extra INTEGER););
```

And to insert I have this code:

```
try (SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("fecha_registro", fechaRegistro.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
            valores.put("latitud", latitud);
            valores.put("longitud", longitud);
            valores.put("id_evento", id_evento);
            valores.put("id_asignacion_proyecto", asignacionProyecto.getId());
            valores.put("codigo_template", codigo_template);
            valores.put("sincronizado", sincronizado);
            valores.put("imei_telefono", imei_telefono);
            valores.put("cedula_supervisor", cedulaSupervisor);

            if (esExtra)
                valores.put("es_extra", 1);
            else
                valores.put("es_extra", 0);

            long resultado = db.insertOrThrow("registro", null, valores);

            return resultado > 0;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.uploadLog(mContext, ex);
            Log.e(TAG, "Error guardando registro", ex);
            return false;
        }
```

Everything is fine. Why am I getting this error on some tablets?

Answer (score 0):

You may have created the table before without that column.

One alternative would be to drop the table and create it again.

Another thing you can try is to run a query like this, perhaps before the `insert`

```
select * from sqlite_master where name="registro" and type="table"
```

and log the result.

Yet another alternative would be to insert all the values first and the `es_extra`

```
try (SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("fecha_registro", fechaRegistro.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
            valores.put("latitud", latitud);
            valores.put("longitud", longitud);
            valores.put("id_evento", id_evento);
            valores.put("id_asignacion_proyecto", asignacionProyecto.getId());
            valores.put("codigo_template", codigo_template);
            valores.put("sincronizado", sincronizado);
            valores.put("imei_telefono", imei_telefono);
            valores.put("cedula_supervisor", cedulaSupervisor);

            long resultado = db.insertOrThrow("registro", null, valores);

            valores.clear();
            valores.put("es_extra", esExtra ? 1 : 0);

            // you can add an extra try/catch here 
            db.update("registro", valores, "rowid=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(resultado)});
     
            return resultado > 0;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.uploadLog(mContext, ex);
            Log.e(TAG, "Error guardando registro", ex);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I would like to know what is the cause of this weird error. Because first of all the app never gave me this error on my phone. Secondly I checked to see if there was another `create table registro` and there was no other one. The client uninstall the and install it again it was still giving this same error. Then, the client factory reset the tablet and install the app and now the app is working fine on his tablet. I did not try `drop table registro`. But as soon as the user deleted the app `Android` normally deletes the database. But this time Android failed. It wasn't a programming issue.

Comment: Check you [onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) implementation, you may not be increasing versions

Comment: OnUpgrade get called when the user udate the app. But if the user uninstall the app and then install the app *after uninstalled it*. onUpgrade doesn't matter in that case. Am I wrong?